# New row button not showing when no data present

Tags: asp.net

Aspx, Entity, on my gridView I made a footer for a new button. It shows when there are items, but not when data is empty. gridView's ShowFooter = True. Not sure why it won't show when empty, is there another property I maybe missing? I know a workaround could be place a dummy row in the database, but think there should be a better way to start off at 0. If you have any more questions, please ask.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="New" >
        <FooterTemplate >
         <asp:Button ID="btnNew" CssClass="DDButton" runat="server" Text="New" CommandName="New" OnClick="new_item" />
        </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: The footer-template is not shown when no data is present, only the `EmptyDataTemplate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net 4.0 added the `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty` property on the GridView but unfortunately no `ShowFooterWhenEmpty`. However there is still the `EmptyDataTemplate`:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="myGridView">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnNew" CssClass="DDButton" runat="server" Text="New" CommandName="New" OnClick="new_item" />
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

As this will not be in a `GridViewRow` I don't think your `RowCommand` event will fire but you seem to be handling the click of the button in a separate method anyway.

Reference for `GridView.EmptyDataTemplate`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate.aspx

Comment: No problem, if you've never had need of it before, and you don't religiously read the docs you're not going to know about it ^_^

Answer (score 2):

The footer-template is not shown when no data is present, only the [`EmptyDataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate.aspx).

```
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnNew" runat="server" 
        Text="New" CommandName="New"
        CssClass="DDButton"
        OnClick="new_item" />
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```